# Extracting Road Terrain Properties using DEM / LIDAR

Tags: data, dem, lidar, terrain, extract

I want to extract following road terrain data from DEM but I'm not sure if its possible. Can i extract these attributes using LIDAR if not DEM ?

These are the data fields I need:

*Horizontal curve location, Horizontal curve length,    Grade in direction of travel,   Roadway elevation,  Roadway elevation,  Vertical curve location,    Vertical curve length,  Available sight distance,   Road cross slope, Shoulder cross slope*

Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to GIS SE!

Based what I've come across, you should be able to extract most if not all the attributes you are interested in from LiDAR data.

Based on this article - [Forest Roads Mapped Using LiDAR in Steep Forested Terrain](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/2/4/1120/htm)

> Road parameters extracted from LiDAR data on US highways include; evaluation of line-of-sight visibility and stopping distance for horizontal and vertical road curves [41], use of road slope data to model precipitation runoff from road surfaces, and assessment of slope-length limitations for heavy trucks [42]. While LiDAR has proven useful in a variety of transportation planning and natural resources applications, it is regarded as a relatively new technology, and one which requires a considerable investment [43]. For many, the role of LiDAR in supporting resource management activities remains unclear. Important questions regarding the accuracy, capabilities, and efficiency of LiDAR-based methods must still be addressed before these methods can be justified and more broadly adopted into resource management workflows.

The article provides sections that cover which provide examples of how you may approach this:
Study Approach
Methods
Results

I just wanted to share a source that can be used to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response . This was really helpful :)